# How to access application object from ModuleEvent in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need my ZF2 module to wait until all modules have been loaded that might overwrite my module's config. I then need to extract some values from the merged config and attach a listener to the shared event manager.

In my module I have this;

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
    // Listen for when all other modules have been loaded.
    $eventManager = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_LOAD_MODULES_POST, array($this, 'onModulesLoadedPost'));

}

private function onModulesLoadedPost(ModuleEvent $event)
{
    $config = $event->getConfigListener()->getMergedConfig(false)['MyConfigKey'];
    $sharedEventManager = // HELP, How do i get the shared event manager here?

    // listen for new roles (if configured)
    if ($config['new_role_event_id'] != '') { 
        $param = $config['new_role_event_param'];
        $sharedEventManager->attach($config['new_role_event_id'], $config['new_role_event'], function($e) use($serviceManager, $param) {
            $role = $e->getParam($param)->getId();
            $service = $serviceManager->get('CivAccess\AclService');
            $service->addRole($role, 'user');
        }, 100);
    }

}
```

In the onModulesLoadedPost function how do I access the shared event manager? (You can see I also need to grab the service manager.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP` if you require the Service Manager in your listener. By the time the bootstrap event occurs, all the configuration is already merged together.

You can use the `onBootstrap` method to check the config, and add the listener if needed.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application  = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $config = $application->getServiceManager()->get('Config');

    if (! empty($config['new_role_event_id'])) {
        $eventManager->attach($config['new_role_event_id'], $config['new_role_event'], [$this, 'addAclRole']);
    }
}

public function addAclRole(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');

    $role = $event->getParam($config['new_role_event_param']);
    $aclService = $serviceManager->get('CivAccess\AclService');

    $aclService->addRole($role, 'user');
}
```

One caveat of adding an ACL role using the event system is that the listener will *always* be added; regardless on whether the ACL service `CivAccess\AclService` is required in that particular request.

You could avoid this by moving all the above logic into the service *factory* that creates the `CivAccess\AclService`.